# Resampling with gdalwarp results in IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python, bash, resampling, sentinel2

I work with Sentinel2 images and I'm trying to resample them.

I tried the following code:

```
import os, fnmatch

INPUT_FOLDER = "/d/afavro/Bureau/test_resampling/original"
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "/d/afavro/Bureau/test_resampling/resampling_10m"

    def findRasters (path, filter):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
                yield file

    for raster in findRasters(INPUT_FOLDER,'*.tif'):
        print(raster)
        inRaster = INPUT_FOLDER + '/' + raster
        print(inRaster)
        outRaster = OUTPUT_FOLDER + '/resample' + raster
        print (outRaster)
        cmd = "gdalwarp -tr 10 10 -r cubic " % (inRaster,outRaster)
        os.system(cmd)
```

But I still get the same error message :

```
def findRasters (path, filter): ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I already tried the same type of code to make a subset and it worked. I don't understand where my mistake came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error type `IndentationError` should be taken literally: Your indentation seems to be wrong. Your line

```
def findRasters (path, filter):
```

is too far indented, but needs to be at the same indentation level as the previous line

```
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "/d/afavro/Bureau/test_resampling/resampling_10m"
```

The full code sample you provided should look like this:

```
import os, fnmatch

INPUT_FOLDER = "/d/afavro/Bureau/test_resampling/original"
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "/d/afavro/Bureau/test_resampling/resampling_10m"

def findRasters (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield file

for raster in findRasters(INPUT_FOLDER,'*.tif'):
    print(raster)
    inRaster = INPUT_FOLDER + '/' + raster
    print(inRaster)
    outRaster = OUTPUT_FOLDER + '/resample' + raster
    print (outRaster)
    cmd = "gdalwarp -tr 10 10 -r cubic " % (inRaster,outRaster)
    os.system(cmd)
```

---

Also, as you've written in the additional comment, your line

```
cmd = "gdalwarp -tr 10 10 -r cubic " % (inRaster,outRaster)
```

seems to be wrong as `inRaster` and `outRaster` won't be used in the string. Use [String formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead:

```
cmd = 'gdalwarp -tr 10 10 -r cubic "{}" "{}"'.format(inRaster, outRaster)
```

Comment: Yes, I just realized it, thank you very much!
Now I have a message that says:
    File "<ipython-input-34-b5b6dcbc2ae7>", line 18, in <module> cmd = "gdalwarp -tr 10 10 10 -r cubic" % (inRaster,outRaster) 

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I think there is an argument missing in the bracket of my order... I don't have a good command of the bash codes